# Caveats: having main as a stateful widget

Tags: dart, flutter

Are there any drawbacks to having my root as a `StatefulWidget` as opposed to a `StatelessWidget`? The reason is I would like to give ThemeData control to the settings menu of my app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. It does not make any difference. You can even call `setState` without performance bottleneck.